# Alimentar Array PrimeFaces

Tags: array, primefaces, eclipse

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Tenho 2 tabela relacionadas, uma de pedidos e outra de itens do pedido, logo eu pensei em alimentar um array com as informações dos itens do pedido e na mesma tela colocar informações do pedido e quando clicasse no botão de gravar pedido ele gravaria o pedido e persistiria o array no banco com as informações do array.
Mas o array esta estranho, ele cria e aparece, mas quando eu crio outro objeto dentro dele, ele altera todos os objetos doa array para o ultimo criado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
    quando eu insiro outro item:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele altera todo o Array.

Segue o código:

XHTML:

```
<ui:define name="titulo">
    Novo Pedido
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:form>
        <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />

        <fieldset style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <legend>Dados do Pedido</legend>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">           

            <h:outputLabel value="Data do Abertura:" for="dataAbertura" />

            <p:calendar id="dataAbertura"
                    value="#{pedidoBean.pedido.dataAbertura.time}"
                    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" />                                        

             <h:outputText value="Pedido Entregue: " />
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{pedidoBean.pedido.pedidoEntregue}" />     


                <p:outputLabel value="Fornecedor:" for="fornecedor" />  

                <p:autoComplete id="fornecedor" value="#{pedidoBean.fornecedorId}" 
                            completeMethod="#{pedidoBean.completeText}" 
                            var="fornecedor" itemLabel="#{fornecedor.nome}" itemValue="#{fornecedor}"
                            converter="fornecedorConverter" 
                            forceSelection="true" >
                             <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{pedidoBean.gravarFornecedor}" process="@form"/> 
                </p:autoComplete> 


            <h:outputLabel value="Data do Fechamento:" for="dataConcluido" />

            <p:calendar id="dataConcluido"
                    value="#{pedidoBean.pedido.dataConcluido.time}"
                    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" />    

            </h:panelGrid>
            <br/>               
            <h:panelGrid>
            <f:facet name="footer"   style="float: right;">
                <p:commandButton value="Salvar Pedido" action="#{pedidoBean.gravarPedido}"/>
            </f:facet>
            </h:panelGrid>
        <br/>

            </fieldset>     



        <br/>   


        <fieldset style="float: left; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: -20px;">
            <legend>Itens do Pedido</legend>

            <h:panelGrid columns="4" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >
            <h:form id="itensPedidos">
            <p:outputLabel value="Produto:" for="produto" />        

            <h:outputLabel value="Quantidade: " for="quantidade" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Preço: " for="preco" />

            <h:outputLabel value=""/>

                <p:autoComplete id="produto" value="#{pedidoBean.produtoId}" 
                            completeMethod="#{pedidoBean.completeTextProduto}" 
                            var="produto" itemLabel="#{produto.nome}" itemValue="#{produto}"
                            converter="produtoConverter" 
                            forceSelection="true" >
                             <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{pedidoBean.gravarProduto}" 
                                process="@form"/> 
                </p:autoComplete> 


                    <p:inputText id="quantidade" value="#{pedidoBean.itensPedido.quantidade}" />    

                    <p:inputText id="preco" value="#{pedidoBean.itensPedido.valorPedido}" />    
                            </h:form>
                    <p:commandButton value="Salvar Item" action="#{pedidoBean.gravarItensPedido}" 
                     update="tabela" process="@this itensPedidos"/>

            </h:panelGrid>


            <p:dataTable value="#{pedidoBean.itensDoPedido}" var="itensPedido"
                    id="tabela">    
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Produto</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{itensPedido.produto.nome}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Quantidade</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{itensPedido.quantidade}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Valor Pedido</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{itensPedido.valorPedido}" />
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

</fieldset>


            <br/>           

    </h:form>



</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

PedidoBean:

```
public class PedidoBean {

    private Fornecedor fornecedor;
    private List<Fornecedor> fornecedores;
    private Integer fornecedorId;
    private Integer produtoId;
    private int number1;   
    private String txt1;
    private Pedido pedido = new Pedido();   
    private ItensPedido itensPedido = new ItensPedido();


    /* Gravar Fornecedor */
    public List<Fornecedor> getFornecedores() {
        return new DAO<Fornecedor>(Fornecedor.class).listaTodos();
    }

    public List<Fornecedor> completeText(String query) {

        System.out.println("Entrou: ");

        this.fornecedores = new DAO<Fornecedor>(Fornecedor.class).listaTodos();
        List<Fornecedor> results =  new ArrayList<Fornecedor>();
        for(Fornecedor p : this.fornecedores) {
            if (p.getNome().startsWith(query)) {
                results.add(p);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public void gravarFornecedor() {

        Fornecedor fornecedor = new DAO<Fornecedor>(Fornecedor.class).buscaPorId(this.fornecedorId);
        this.pedido.adicionaFornecedor(fornecedor);

    }

    /* Gravar Produto em itensPedido */

    private List<Produto> produtos;

    public List<Produto> completeTextProduto(String query) {

        System.out.println("Entrou: ");

        this.produtos = new DAO<Produto>(Produto.class).listaTodos();
        List<Produto> results =  new ArrayList<Produto>();
        for(Produto p : this.produtos) {
            if (p.getNome().startsWith(query)) {
                results.add(p);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public void gravarProduto() {

        System.out.println("O nome do autor é: "+ produtoId);

        Produto produto = new DAO<Produto>(Produto.class).buscaPorId(this.produtoId);
        this.itensPedido.adicionaProduto(produto);
        System.out.println("O nome do produto é: "+ produto.getNome());

    }

    /*Getters and Setters */
    public Pedido getPedido() {
        return pedido;
    }

    public Integer getFornecedorId() {
        return fornecedorId;
    }

    public void setFornecedorId(Integer fornecedorId) {
        this.fornecedorId = fornecedorId;
    }

    public int getNumber1() {
        return number1;
    }

    public void setNumber1(int number1) {
        this.number1 = number1;
    }

    public String getTxt1() {
        return txt1;
    }

    public void setTxt1(String txt1) {
        this.txt1 = txt1;
    }

    public Fornecedor getFornecedor() {
        return fornecedor;
    }

    public void setFornecedor(Fornecedor fornecedor) {
        this.fornecedor = fornecedor;
    }

    public String getNomeFornecedor (){
        return fornecedor.getNome();
    }

    public Integer getProdutoId() {
        return produtoId;
    }

    public void setProdutoId(Integer produtoId) {
        this.produtoId = produtoId;
    }
    /////Getters Setters    
    public List<ItensPedido> getItensPedidos() {
        return new DAO<ItensPedido>(ItensPedido.class).listaTodos();
    }

    public List<ItensPedido> getItensDoPedido(){
        return this.pedido.getItensPedido();
    }

    public List<Pedido> getPedidos() {
        return new DAO<Pedido>(Pedido.class).listaTodos();
    }

    public ItensPedido getItensPedido() {
        return itensPedido;
    }

    public void setItensPedido(ItensPedido itensPedido) {
        this.itensPedido = itensPedido;
    }

    /////Metodos
    public void gravarItensPedido() {
        System.out.println ("Agora vai: " + itensPedido.getValorPedido());
        System.out.println ("Agora vai: " + pedido.getItensPedido());
        this.pedido.adicionaItensPedido(itensPedido);
    }

}
```

Comment: Pode postar o código da classe ItensPedido?

Answer (score 0):

Opa, claro:

`public class ItensPedidoBean implements Serializable{

```
private Produto produto;
private List<Produto> produtos;
private Integer produtoId;
private String txt1;
private ItensPedido itensPedido = new ItensPedido();
private List<ItensPedido> itensPedidos = new ArrayList<ItensPedido>();
private int number1;    
private Pedido pedido;

public List<ItensPedido> getItensPedidos() {
    return itensPedidos;
}

public void setItensPedidos(List<ItensPedido> itensPedidos) {
    this.itensPedidos = itensPedidos;
}

public Integer getProdutoId() {
    return produtoId;
}

public void setProdutoId(Integer produtoId) {
    this.produtoId = produtoId;
}

public ItensPedido getItensPedido() {
    return itensPedido;
}

public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
    return new DAO<Produto>(Produto.class).listaTodos();
}

public List<Produto> completeTextProduto(String query) {

    System.out.println("Entrou: ");

    this.produtos = new DAO<Produto>(Produto.class).listaTodos();
    List<Produto> results =  new ArrayList<Produto>();
    for(Produto p : this.produtos) {
        if (p.getNome().startsWith(query)) {
            results.add(p);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

public Produto getProdutosPedido (){
    return this.itensPedido.getProduto();
}



public void gravarProduto() {

    System.out.println("O nome do autor é: "+ produtoId);

    Produto produto = new DAO<Produto>(Produto.class).buscaPorId(this.produtoId);
    this.itensPedido.adicionaProduto(produto);
    System.out.println("O nome do produto é: "+ produto.getNome());

}

public List<ItensPedido> getItensDoPedidos() {
    for(int i=0;i<pedido.getItensPedido().size();i++){
          System.out.println("O item é:" + pedido.getItensPedido().get(i).getQuantidade() + pedido.getItensPedido().get(i).getProduto().getNome());  
    }   
    return this.pedido.getItensPedido();
}


public Produto getProduto() {
    return produto;
}

public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
    this.produto = produto;
}

public String getTxt1() {
    return txt1;
}

public void setTxt1(String txt1) {
    this.txt1 = txt1;
}

public int getNumber1() {
    return number1;
}

public void setNumber1(int number1) {
    this.number1 = number1;
}

public String formItensPedido(){
    return "pedido?faces-redirect=true";
}


}
```

Modelo ItensPedido:

```
@Entity 
@Embeddable

public class ItensPedido {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private int quantidade;
private double valorPedido;


@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private Produto produto = new Produto();

public Produto getProduto() {
    return produto;
}

public void adicionaProduto(Produto produto) {
    this.produto = produto;
}
public ItensPedido (){
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
}

public void setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
}

public double getValorPedido() {
    return valorPedido;
}

public void setValorPedido(double valorPedido) {
    this.valorPedido = valorPedido;
}

}
```

Comment: O getItensPedido da sua classe Pedido é certeza que contém todos valores vindos do banco de dados? Porque o datatable está utilizando essa lista.

Comment: E você pode editar sua resposta, não é preciso adicionar uma nova para mostrar mais código :]

Comment: Douglas, não queria que ele gravasse os itens no banco até finalizar a criação de todos e o pedido.
Ai pensei em alimentar um array e só quando o botão gravar na form pedidos for acionado ele grava todos os itens do array no banco e o pedido tb.
Não acha ideal essa solução?

Comment: Bom dia pessoal, Ninguém? rs